# WPF Combo Box Data Binding Selected Item

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm

I am trying to databind a `ComboBox` to a list of `strings`. So far I have got the following:

In my View I have:

```
<ComboBox Height="23" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          Margin="133,180,0,0" 
          Name="comboBox1" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Hours}" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          Width="38" />
```

And in my ViewModel I have:

```
private List<string> tripTimeHours = new List<string>();
private List<string> tripTimeMinutes = new List<string>();

public CreateTripViewModel()
{
    TripName = new DataWrapper<string>(this, tripNameChangeArgs);
    TripName.IsEditable = true;
    setObjects();
    CreateTripFiredCommand = new SimpleCommand<object, EventToCommandArgs>(ExecuteCreateTripCommand);
}

private void setObjects()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
    {
        tripTimeHours.Add(i.ToString());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
    {
        tripTimeMinutes.Add(i.ToString());
    }
}

public List<string> Hours
{
    get
    {
        return tripTimeHours;
    }
}

public List<string> Minutes
{
    get
    {
        return tripTimeMinutes;
    }
}
```

What I want to be able to do is return the selected item from these combo boxes. I think I'm almost there, but just need to complete the final step.

Comment: What is it actually doing at the moment? Are you getting an error or anything? What have you tried so far?

Comment: At the moment I am getting the values in the combo box and that's all I've got so far. I can't work out the logic for getting the selected item.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add a binding to `ComboBox.SelectedItem` which is bound to a new `string` property on your ViewModel

```
<ComboBox ITemsSource="{Binding Hours}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" />

class ViewModel
{
    public string SelectedItem {get; set;}
}
```