# wpf get value by name?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

on WPF on c# i have combobox

```
     <ComboBox x:Name="listCombobox" />
```

and i add it item like

```
var list = new[]
 { 
new { Number = 1, Name = "Smith" },
new { Number = 12, Name = "John" } ,
new { Number = 14, Name = "Bon" } 

}.ToList();

foreach (var item in list)
{
   listCombobox.Items.Add(item.Name);
 }
```

what i want that on the combobox i will see the Name(like now)

but when i selected , on the code behind i will see not the name i selected 
i want to see the Number that selected

thanks!

Comment: Have a look at this SO answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19071664/wpf-how-to-bind-object-to-combobox

Comment: And also this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186234/wpf-combo-box-data-binding-selected-item

Answer (score 1):

Define a class like this

```
public class dataObject 
{
   public  int Number { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }            
}
```

And fill the data,

```
         List<dataObject> bindingList = new List<dataObject>();          
         bindingList.Add(new dataObject()
         {
             Name = "Smith",
             Number = 1
         });
         bindingList.Add(new dataObject()
         {
             Name = "John",
             Number = 12
         });
         bindingList.Add(new dataObject()
         {
             Name = "Bon",
             Number = 14
         });
        listCombobox.ItemsSource = bindingList;
        listCombobox.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
```

On selectionChanged event of the combobox, do this,

```
private void listCombobox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            dataObject result = (dataObject)listCombobox.SelectedItem;
            var selectedNumber = result.Number;           
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a custom ListItem class and assign objects of this type to the ItemSource property of the combobox control like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var list = new List<ListItem>
         {
            new ListItem{ Value = 1, Text = "Smith" },
            new ListItem{ Value = 12, Text = "John" } ,
            new ListItem{ Value = 14, Text = "Bon" }
        }.ToList();

        listCombobox.ItemsSource = list;
        listCombobox.DisplayMemberPath = "Text";
        listCombobox.SelectedValuePath = "Value";
    }

    private void listCombobox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedItem = (sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem as ListItem;
        if (selectedItem != null)
        {
            // do something with the selected item
        }
    }
}

public class ListItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way, I think, is to put these numbers as Tag of every `listCombobox` item:

```
foreach (var item in list) {
    listCombobox.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem { Content = item.Name, Tag = item.Number });
}
```

And access your number (`OnSelectedItemchanged`, for example):

```
void Cb_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
    int number = (int)((ComboBoxItem) listCombobox.SelectedItem).Tag;
}
```

Comment: how please?
can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

I would solve it as follows:

```
...

foreach (var item in list)
    listCombobox.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem() {
        Content = item.Name,
        Tag = item.Number
    });
```

You can of course retrieve your Data by using

```
int mytag = listCombobox.Items[3].Tag;
```

or

```
int seletected = listCombobox.SelectedItem.Tag;
```

---

MSDN Reference for [PresentationFramework.dll::System.Windows.Frameworkelement.Tag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: [@Alex Butenko](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1295010/alex-butenko): funny, we posted our answers at the same time ^^